# Sql Azure Getting Data From Stored Procedures With IN C# MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, ssms

I am new to sql server azure.Basically i Need to execute a stored procedure with the parameters which will return the data. I want to know how can i get that data in View Model.Its gives me the message "Child evalution not allowed".I have gone through external tables.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For the most part, Azure SQL Database is very much similar to SQL Server on premises. If you know how to call a stored procedure which returns some data and use that in your application, you should be using exact same thing here as well (it's a connection string change). If you're asking for sample code for the same, I would request you to search for the same. I am sure you will find a lot of samples for that. HTH.

Comment: Is there any concept of external tables that can be usef or how to populate views from stored procedures.